# How to generate proper SQL for MySQL with jOOQ with UUID fields?

Tags: mysql, uuid, jooq

I'm using jOOQ 3.9.1 and try to generate table with UUID field.

```
val sql = dsl.createTable("test").column("id", SQLDataType.UUID).column("val", SQLDataType.UUID.length(36).nullable(false)).getSQL()
```

Expected result is:

```
create table `test`(`id` varchar(36) null, `val` varchar(36) not null)
```

But I got:

```
create table `test`(`id` varchar null, `val` varchar not null)
```

What I did wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known issue in jOOQ 3.9.1 and earlier versions:
https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/5807

The easiest workaround would be to:

1. Use [plain SQL](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/plain-sql/) here for the entire statement
2. Use an [`ExecuteListener`](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-execution/execute-listeners/) to patch the generated SQL output

Comment: Thank you @LukasEder. It seems what the ExecuteListener is the best approach to keep the DB agnosticism - the best property of jOOQ.
This approach allows to change code generation only for the specific DB by checking the dialect before changes.